# Unifying OCaml patterns through function composition

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, unification

Suppose that I have defined manually some code like that:

```
type test  = A of bool | B | C of bool * bool 
type test2 = D | E of bool * bool 
type test3 = F | G of bool | H of bool

let f = function | A(x) -> E(x,true) | B -> D | C(a,b) -> E(b,a)

let g = function  | D -> F | E(a,b) -> if a then G(b) else H(b)
```

Now I want to evaluate the composition g ∘ f as a function that does not require to use the intermediate representation `test2`. I've been thinking about structure unification, but I'm asking the following questions:

1. does OCaml automatically perform such unification when declaring `let h x = g (f x)`?
2. If not, does a general algorithm exist that could be implemented in OCaml in order to `compile` into an ml file such desired h?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know about OCaml but GHC could probably do this by inlining f and g, then applying case-of-case and case-of-known-constructor.

Comment: Ok… I'd prefer to stick with only one language, though (all the rest of my code is written in OCaml). By the way, thanks for the insight.

Comment: @melpomene, well, any language "could probably" do anything... Do you have real proof that GHC will do this?

Comment: @ivg No. This is in response to 2. "does a general algorithm exist ...?"

Comment: @ivg, So, he means that I could implement such algorithm in Haskell.

Comment: @jackb That's not what I mean at all.

Comment: @melpomene, So? If neither I can "code" it in Haskell (my interpretation), neither such implemented in GHC (ivg's), then what's your point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Disclaimer

I'm not an OCaml compiler developer. If you want to get their opinion then it is better to contact them on the mailing list.

## Part 1

Theoretically, the modern OCaml (I've tried with 4.0{3,4}+flambda) is capable of eliminating some intermediate data structures of type `test2`. However, to achieve this you need to pass special optimization options, and add `[@@inlined always]` to function `f`, otherwise it is not inlined even with crazy inline options like `-inline 10000` and `-inline-toplevel 10000`.

However, in general case and for bigger functions this might not work. Here I suppose, that the example, that you've shown is a toy example, and in real life you're facing with much bigger functions and more than two compositions (i.e., hundreds of constructors with hundreds of compositions), otherwise, it is not worthwhile to optimize this at all).

## Part 2

### Theory

Speaking about the general algorithm, if we will be too picky, then it is impossible, as to the right of `->` in the pattern match there can be any OCaml expression, i.e., a Turing-complete program. So, we have an equivalent of the decision problem. Even if we will restrict the expression language, by disallowing loops and side-effects, the problem would still be NP-hard, so it is probably not worthwhile to try to solve it. However, if we will restrict ourselves even more, by disallowing any expressions except constructor applications with trivial operands, then we will actually encode a Finite State Machine (FSM). There are plenty of well-defined FSM optimization and state minimization algorithms, so it wouldn't be hard to remove redundancy from it.

### Practice

In practice, I wouldn't probably write a function, that translate `ml` code to `ml` code. Depending on my real task I will think about the following approaches.

#### Enumerable set of inputs

If the set of values that inhabit type `test` is practically finite (i.e., if it fits into OCaml array), then I would try to write a function that will enumerate all possible values of type `test`, and store the result of composition. You can use `[@@deriving enumerate]` to compute all possible values of type `test`

```
# type test  = A of bool | B | C of bool * bool [@@deriving enumerate];;
type test = A of bool | B | C of bool * bool
val all_of_test : test list =
  [A false; A true; B; C (false, false); C (true, false); C (false, true);
   C (true, true)]
```

Then, you can assign an ordinal to each value of type `test` and have an O(1) transformation to type `test3`. Also, there will be no allocations at all, since we already precomputed all constructors beforehand.

However, you will still need to transform `test -> int` for our approach to work, and this operation will require `log(k)` branches where `k` is the number of constructors in type `test`. From the big-O notation perspective, `k` is constant. But if it is really big, then you can try to make all your constructors argumentless, e.g., by representing `A of bool` as two constructors `A_true` and `A_false`. In this case, you will have pure O(1) transformation with no overhead (just an array dereference).

#### Enumerable input with uninterpreted functions

If there are constructors that bear values of type `int` or `string`, then it is practically impossible to enumerate them. However, if transformation `h` doesn't look at this values, but just rearrange them, i.e., treat them as [Uninterpreted functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterpreted_function), then you should try to decouple this arguments from you input language by using GADT. Suppose you have the following data constructor:

```
| C of string
```

And result `h (C s)` is the same for all `s`. Then there is no need to pass `s` into `h` at all. However, you still want to pass a payload `s` to some other function, for example, to `exec`. It is possible to do with GADT, first we will decouple the payload from the constructor:

```
| C : string query
```

And then we will be able to pass the query to a function as two different parameters:

```
val exec : 'a query -> 'a -> unit
```

#### General case

If the two cases above didn't apply to you, then you need to write your own compiler :) It looks like, that you're implementing an interpreter of some language, that uses OCaml as a host language, and you're hoping that OCaml will do the optimizations for you. Well, OCaml is indeed not a bad choice to write interpreters, but it can't optimize your DSL, because it doesn't know the semantics of your DSL. And clever application of the semantics rules, is what all optimizations are about. So, that means, that if you're unsatisfied with the performance of your interpreter, then you need to write your own optimizing compiler. First of all, you will need to design, the abstract machine on which you will execute your queries, and then write an optimizer that is targeted to this machine.

Comment: Indeed, this is only a toy example. I'm implementing a query language, and so there are a lot of distinct cases and rewritings in there. As a consequence, I think that in my case I cannot enumerate all the possible cases (See, I could have strings too as part of my constructors, such as attributes or values). So I think that in this case I cannot enumerate all the possible elements (ps. So, in your solution, I have *two* declarations for the same data type?)

Comment: The second is just a reply from the REPL (I've added `#` to make it more obvious). So, if your real-world problem, includes practically non-enumerable types, but these types are not interpreted by the `h` transformation, then probably you should decouple them from your query language. You can use GADT for that. But, probably, it would be easier, not to try to encode your query in a host language, but to solve it directly. _Just_, write an AST, and then do the regular query language optimization.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. So, what I ment is that I could have an AST as intermediate representation of my language, but such "function-composition part" only invoves intermediate rewritings of my AST into other languages (Such as SQL is rewritten in Relational Algebra, for example), and does not involve query optimizations (yet). So I'm always dealing with "GADT"s, but the only thing is that it could be `C("hi","there")` and, in this case, I cannot enumerate all the possible strings.

Comment: (In particular, I'm referring to the `val all_of_test : test list`).

Comment: When I was proposing to use GADT, I meant that you should use `C : (string * string) query`  query constructor, instead of `C of string * string`, and to pass your query as two values, the query type (kind) and the query payload, e.g., `'a query -> 'a`. With such encoding, every query will be an immediate value, that doesn't require an allocation. If you will couple this approach with CPS, then you will get rid of any allocations at all. This will make your code already very efficient.

Comment: As I mentioned, now the GADT stuff is indeed clear to me (thanks for the reply update).  As a reply for your general case: well, this only spring to mind since for the moment I have different intermediate representations of the same query, so I'm only rewriting queries represented differently (I don't want to merge intermediate representations manually, since such task is more prone to human error). (continues…)

Comment: Either if I compile my query language or if I interpret it and then execute it, I think that i would obtain the same result. The thing that I want is to provide a direct translation from the Human-Readable notation, into a query language which could be better optimized by the machine. But in order to do so, there are some intermediate AST rewritings I have to do between different intermediate representations. By the way, at this step, I haven't designed the query-interpretation part, so I think that for the moment your solution is the right thing to do.

Comment: Now, I got the understanding of your problem. Probably, you should consider using abstraction to hide two different representations, so that you do not need to do a concrete transformation. If this doesn't work for you, then make sure that you can really make the concrete transformations fast, if you will get rid of data allocations, i.e., by using nullary GADT constructors, and CPS to pass data between functions. Once it is done, the transformation would be just a pure arithmetics, so you can do billions of them in a second.

Answer (score 2):

For old versions of OCaml, this is not sure.

However, if you activate the [flambda optimization](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/flambda.html), you can be pretty sure you will profit from that kind of optimization.

Note that flambda must be activated while building your compiler (if you use opam, there is a dedicated switch). Your compilation time may be a bit longer but it is totally worth it.

If you want to be sure it will be inlined (and therefore simplified), you can use the `[@@inline always]` attribute on your function declaration or `[@@inlined always]` on your function call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck to OCaml's Reference Manual written 7 years ago and some older stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, take a look at the latest language features, you can get a lot from it.